# How to merge 2 ordered dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 ordered dictionaries, like:

```
a = collections.OrderedDict()
b = collections.OrderedDict()
```

And they have stuff in them. How do I merge these 2? I tried:

```
mergeDict = dict(a.items() + b.items())
```

but doing this it's not a ordered dictionary anymore.

What I am looking for: if `a = {1, 2, 5, 6}` and `b = [0, 7, 3, 9}` then `mergeDict = {1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 7, 3, 9}`

Comment: What order are you looking for in the merge?

Comment: `a.update(b)` ?

Comment: @alfasin I was thinking the same thing. Looked for a documentation on OrderedDict.update but it appears to be the same as dict.update. Still, the docstring says it does `for k, v in E: D[k] = v` so it should keep the order.

Comment: Does merge mean append?

Comment: There are many ways to merge two dictionaries, which is why Python doesn't try to pick one of them as a definition for `{...} + {...}`. What result do you *want*?

Comment: I am looking for, in a = {1, 2, 5, 6} and b = [0, 7, 3, 9}then mergeDict = {1, 2, 5, 6, 0, 7, 3, 9}

Comment: That `a = {1, 2, 5, 6}` is a set, not a dict. And that `b` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 37):

Two ways (assuming Python 3.6):

1. Use "update method". Suppose there are two dictionaries:

   ```
   >>> d1 = collections.OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
   >>> d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
   >>> d1.update(d2)
   >>> d1
   OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
   ```
2. Second method using 'concatenation operator (+)'

   ```
   >>> d1 = collections.OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
   >>> d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}
   >>> d3 = collections.OrderedDict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))
   >>> d3
   OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])
   ```

Comment: OP specifies `OrderedDict`.

Comment: This works with `OrderedDict` as well.  In both cases, if `d1` is an `OrderedDict`, `d2` can be either a `dict` or `OrderedDict`.

I came here looking for an answer to the same problem and just tested it out in a python3.6 shell.  They work.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(chain(a.items(), b.items()))
```

Comment: doesn't recognize "chain". I am using python 2.7

Comment: It's in the itertools module `from itertools import chain`

Answer (score 4):

CPython 3.6, and any 3.7+ interpreter already preserves dictionary key ordering.
This allows you to do use the `{**a, **b}` syntax.

For example:

```
>>> a = {1: "AA", 2: "BB", 5: "CC", 6: "DD"}
>>> b = {0: "EE", 7: "FF", 3: "GG", 9: "HH"}
>>> {**a, **b}
{1: 'AA', 2: 'BB', 5: 'CC', 6: 'DD', 0: 'EE', 7: 'FF', 3: 'GG', 9: 'HH'}
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of dict use back OrderedDict for mergeDict

```
mergeDict = collections.OrderedDict(a.items() + b.items())
```

Remark :this only works for python 2.x, add list() over dict.items() for python 3 because dict.items() no longer return list that support + operation

or use `a.update(b)` like @alfasin mentions in comment

i try with simple example and both method works well for me

Comment: `dict_items` does not support `operator.add` in python 3.x

Comment: Hi @vdboor, that's the construction I'd prefer, but I'm worried whether that would reliably return an ordered dict of the same a + b formulation.